# lex program to count the Number of Words

Tags: lex

I made the following lex program to count the Number of words in a Textfile. A 'Word' for me is any string that starts with an alphabet and is followed by 0 or more occurrence of alphabets/numbers/_ .

```
%{
int words;
%}

%%
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]* {words++;  printf("%s %d\n",yytext,words);}
.   ;
%%

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc == 2)
    {

        yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        yylex();

        printf("No. of Words : %d\n",words);

        fclose(yyin);
    }

    else
        printf("Invalid No. of Arguments\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The Problem is that for the following Textfile, I am getting the `No. of Words : 13`. I tried printing the yytext and it shows that it is taking `'manav'` from `'9manav'` as a word even though it doesnot match my definition of a word.

I also tried including `[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]* ;` within my code but still shows the same output. I want to know why is this happening and possible ways to avoid it.

Textfile : -

```
the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog cout for
9manav
 -99-7-5 32 69 99 +1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `manav` is perfectly matching your definition of word. The `9` in front of it is matched by the `.` rule. Remember, that white space is not special in lex.

You had the right idea by adding another rule `[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]* ;` but since the ruleset is ambiguous (there are several ways to match the input) order of the rules matters. It's a while I worked with lex but I think putting the new rule before the word rule should work.

Comment: Shouldn't the . Rule simply skip over the '9manav' completely as I am not incrementing the count of 'words' here.

Comment: No it matches just one character at a time. Once the `9` is gone, the word rule kicks in.

Comment: In that case , can you give me an idea how to check for strings strictly starting with [a-zA-z]?

Comment: This depends on your definition of "strictly starting"; unless it is the first thing in the file there will always be another character before it.

Comment: using [0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]* ; as the first rule helped. Thank You!

Comment: Yes, but this will now also eat things like `(abc` where the `abc` should probably be counted as a word: This depends on your requirements of course.